# How to get the Dropped & Replaced transaction information？

Tags: web3js, metamask

[image]

How can I get Replaced by Txn Hash? Just like etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such explicit information in the blockchain.

When there is a dropped & replaced transaction, there are two transactions which:

1. Are from the same wallet address
2. Use the same account nonce
3. The latter transaction has (probably) higher gas price (or miner tip, after EIP-1559)

What happens is that the latter transaction gets mined, and when nodes notice that a transaction with the same nonce & origin has been mined, they drop the previous transaction since it can't be mined anymore.

What you need to do is monitor the network for such transactions. I'm not sure if some node client already provides such functionality out of the box. If not, you need to create it yourself on top of the node.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to monitor the network for such transactions, I am relatively new to this

Comment: Basically I think you need to keep track of each transaction you see, and compare it to previous transactions you've seen

Comment: web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions' [, callback]); Can I achieve my needs？

Comment: That should be ok